# Prolific PL2303 Ubuntu vs Arduino Mega

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port, usb, arduino

I am testing Digitus USB -> RS232 converter, which is using Prolific PL2303 chip. The aim is to connect to GSP module U-blox LEA 6H. I am working on Ubuntu 12.10.
To check if I can run the converter correctly I wired it up to Arduino Mega Serial Port 1.

I have two devices connected:

```
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
Bus 007 Device 003: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
```

The first one is Arduino on /dev/ttyUSB0, the converter on /dev/ttyUSB1. When I use the code below with /dev/ttyUSB0, it works perfectly and I get on serial port monitor numbers 0...118. However, when I change it to ttyUSB1, the outcome is somewhat different. I am sorry for the mess in the code, it is compiled from 3 different tutorials.

The code for PC:

```
#include <stdio.h>    /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>   /* Standard types */
#include <string.h>   /* String function definitions */
#include <unistd.h>   /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <fcntl.h>    /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h>    /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h>  /* POSIX terminal control definitions */
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <iostream>

/* File descriptor for the port */
int fd;
int n;
uint8_t buffer[255];  /* Input buffer */
const char port_name[] = "/dev/ttyUSB0";

int serialport_init(const char* serialport, int baud)
{
    struct termios toptions;
    int fd;

    //fprintf(stderr,"init_serialport: opening port %s @ %d bps\n",
    //        serialport,baud);

    fd = open(serialport, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    if (fd == -1)  {
        perror("init_serialport: Unable to open port ");
        return -1;
    }

    if (tcgetattr(fd, &toptions) < 0) {
        perror("init_serialport: Couldn't get term attributes");
        return -1;
    }
    speed_t brate = baud; // let you override switch below if needed
    switch(baud) {
    case 4800:   brate=B4800;   break;
    case 9600:   brate=B9600;   break;
#ifdef B14400
    case 14400:  brate=B14400;  break;
#endif
    case 19200:  brate=B19200;  break;
#ifdef B28800
    case 28800:  brate=B28800;  break;
#endif
    case 38400:  brate=B38400;  break;
    case 57600:  brate=B57600;  break;
    case 115200: brate=B115200; break;
    }
    cfsetispeed(&toptions, brate);
    cfsetospeed(&toptions, brate);

    // 8N1
    toptions.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    toptions.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    toptions.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    toptions.c_cflag |= CS8;
    // no flow control
    toptions.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;

    toptions.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL;  // turn on READ & ignore ctrl lines
    toptions.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // turn off s/w flow ctrl

    toptions.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG); // make raw
    toptions.c_oflag &= ~OPOST; // make raw

    // see: http://unixwiz.net/techtips/termios-vmin-vtime.html
    toptions.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0;
    toptions.c_cc[VTIME] = 20;

    if( tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &toptions) < 0) {
        perror("init_serialport: Couldn't set term attributes");
        return -1;
    }

    return fd;
}

int main(void){
    fd = serialport_init(port_name, 19200);
    n=-1;
    for(uint8_t i=0; i<255; i++){
        buffer[i]=i;
    }
    n = write(fd, buffer, 120);
    if(n<0){
        fputs("write() failed!\n", stderr);
        printf("ERROR");
        return -1;
    }
    close(fd);
    std::cout << "Port closed";
    return 0;
}
```

Arduino strange output:

253
251
249
247
245
243
241
239
237
235
233
231
229
227
225
223
221
219
217
215
213
211
209
207
205
203
201
199
197
195
193
191
189
187
185
183
181
179
177
175
173
171
169
167
165
163
161
159
157
155
153
151
149
147
145
143
141
139
137
135
133
131
129
127
125
123
121
119
117
115
113
111
109
107
105
103
101
99
97
95
93
91
89
87
85
73
53
33

It seems that the outcome is the input multiplied by two plus one.

Comment: Apparently it is: "why Arduino gets different data over USB->RS232 using its internal converter (it apparently gets the right data then) and using PL2303 (quoting: "Arduino strange output")"?. ;-)

Comment: The problem comes from the fact that both the converter are built to work with max232, max 485 etc. Will try a TTL NOT gate to see if I can invert the levels.